# Generalized Additive Models. Depending on the K dimensions I put I get different results

Tags: r, statistics, gam

This is the first question I ask in the community, so I hope I do it correctly.

Directly to my problem. Basically, I am working on the temporal dynamics of diversity net effects on productivity in forest communities.

In order to analyze this, I have performed generalized additive models (GAMs). I ended up with the following model.

```
model_1<-gam(NE~s(Inv,bs='cr') + 
        s(FdisPC1,bs='cr') + 
        s(CWM_PC1,bs='cr') + 
        s(CWM_PC2,bs='cr') +
        ti(Inv,FdisPC1)+
        ti(Inv,CWM_PC1)+
        ti(Inv,CWM_PC2)+
        s(Block,bs='re'),
      data=BioEffectsTime)
```

where Inv is Inventory (1,2,3...11), FdisPC1, is the functional dispersion of the Principal Component 1 (PC1) of a previous PCA I did, CWM_PC1, is the Community Weighted means of the PC1, CWM_PC2, the same but of the PC2.

Here the results of the model.

[You can see that every smooth term and interaction is highly significant.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcH5Z.png)

However, If I do gam.check(model_1), we can see that I need the increase K dimensions, as edf is close to k'.

[Table of gam.check (model_1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P84Af.png)

So, I performed the same model but now increasing the K value to the maximum I could (i.e.24).

```
model_2<-gam(NE~s(Inv,bs='cr') + 
        s(FdisPC1,k=24,bs='cr') + 
        s(CWM_PC1,k=24,bs='cr') + 
        s(CWM_PC2,k=24,bs='cr') +
        ti(Inv,FdisPC1)+
        ti(Inv,CWM_PC1)+
        ti(Inv,CWM_PC2)+
        s(Block,bs='re'),
      data=BioEffectsTime)
```

[Now we can see that FdisPC1 and CWM_PC1 are not significant anymore.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Ecj.png)

If we do now gam.check (model_2) we see that it looks much better than the previous model.

[Table of gam.check (model_2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0u5g.png)

However, I performed a third model where I put a value of K=20 to see how that affects the model.

```
model_3<-gam(NE~s(Inv,bs='cr') + 
        s(FdisPC1,k=20,bs='cr') + 
        s(CWM_PC1,k=20,bs='cr') + 
        s(CWM_PC2,k=20,bs='cr') +
        ti(Inv,FdisPC1)+
        ti(Inv,CWM_PC1)+
        ti(Inv,CWM_PC2)+
        s(Block,bs='re'),
      data=BioEffectsTime)
```

[Now as we can see, all the smooth terms and interactions are highly significant again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzXcj.png)

If we do again the gam.check of the model, we see it looks good too.

[Table of gam.check(model_3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aovue.png)

At this point, I would select the model_3 because compared to the model_2, it has a lower AIC value.

AIC_model_2 = -2635,98

AIC_model_3 = -2637,106

However, I do not know why a small variation in K-dimensions can affect that much to the result. Do you have any explanation for this?? Am I missing something? And more important, does anyone know how to deal with this?? I am lost at this point and I really do not know which model I should select.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: If you plot the estimated splines for the different models, is there a big difference?

Comment: @J.C.Wahl Thank you for your comment. For model 2( k=24) s(FdisPC1) is almost linear while in model 3 (k=20) is more wiggly (but smooth). But both show the same negative tendency. For the CWM_PC1 it is pretty similar in the both models. And for CWM_PC2, in the first model (k=24) is extremely wiggly while in the second model (k=20) is smoothly wiggly (Again showing a similar pattern). I would show some figures but I do not how to attach an image here ;)

Comment: It is hard to say without the data and a plot, but in general it should be fine to have a k larger then what you actually need, due to regularization. You could try to set `method = "REML"` or `method = "GCV"` to see if this affects the result. To check if one model is significantly better than another you could also do an ANOVA analysis with `anova(mod1, mod2)`.

Comment: @J.C.Wahl it looks that was the problem. If I set method="REML" the models are much more robust. There are no differences depending on a small variation of K. Also the plots of the estimated splines are the same. Besides, I have being reading about this issues, and it is recommended to use 'REML" instead of "GCV". Here the link if you are interested https://github.com/DistanceDevelopment/dsm/wiki/Why-is-the-default-smoothing-method-%22REML%22-rather-than-%22GCV.Cp%22%3F.

Comment: @J.C.Wahl Thank you very much by the way. You helped me a lot. I appreciate it

Comment: Happy to help! Would you accept it if a post it as an answer?

Comment: @J.C.Wahl Absolutely!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without the data and a plot, but in general it should be fine to have a k larger then what you actually need, due to regularization. You could try to set `method = "REML"` or `method = "GCV"` to see if this affects the result. To check if one model is significantly better than another you could also do an ANOVA analysis with `anova(mod1, mod2)`.